# Painted Texture does not appear when rendered

Tags: texture-painting

I painted this Amazon figure after creating an image called 'metallic'. I painted this material and the figure looks the way I want. However, none of this paint shows up when I render it. I realize there's another image called _17054_Amazon which didn't get painted.
[image]
I'm new to Blender and I'm this is a noob mistake. I'm confused there are two images, but one figure. Can I replace image _17054_Amazon with the iamge 'metallic'?[image]

Comment: how does your Shader Editor look like? You need to plug an Image Texture node (with the image loaded) into a Diffuse

Answer (score 1):

are the materials set correctly?
did you save the image? last version that I used only renders the saved file.

Comment: I agree with this troubleshoot. Save the file, then go back into the shader editor and ensure the correct image file is plugged into the shader. If that doesn’t work, send us a picture of what it looks like rendered.